# Simulating button click from another class in winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, tic-tac-toe

I want to create a little "AI" for my Tic Tac Toe, that I've created with Windows Forms, but I am not able to simulate a button getting clicked by the AI of the AI-class. I either need to do this or just change the background of the button. This is only possible, when I am doing it from a non-static method in the class of the button-form. Is there any other way to get this to work?

In the following you can see the most important code ( I omitted some methods of the PlayArea-class) - it is not working, because an object reference is required for the non-static method PlayArea.SimulateButtonClick - I have allready tried a lot to fix this, but stuff like creating an object of the PlayArea-form and refering to it does not help

```
    public partial class PlayArea : Form
    {

        public static WinningScreen winningScreen;
        public int counter = 0;
        public int seconds = 0;

        public PlayArea()
        {
            Program.oldCurrentPlayer = Program.currentPlayer;
            Program.oldEnemyPlayer = Program.enemyPlayer;

            InitializeComponent();

            textBox1.BackColor = Program.currentPlayer.color;
            textBox2.BackColor = Program.currentPlayer.color;
            scoreBox.Text = Program.player1.score.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonPressed(button1, 0, 0);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonPressed(button2, 0, 1);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonPressed(button3, 0, 2);
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonPressed(button4, 1, 0);
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonPressed(button5, 1, 1);
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonPressed(button6, 1, 2);
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonPressed(button7, 2, 0);
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonPressed(button8, 2, 1);
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonPressed(button9, 2, 2);
        }

        public void ButtonPressed(Button button, int x, int y)
        {
            if (Program.currentPlayer.storage[x, y] != true && Program.enemyPlayer.storage[x, y] != true)
            {
                Program.PlaySound("D:/eigenes/Programmieren/Sounds/mixkit-positive-interface-click-1112.wav");
                colorChoice(button);
                playerSwitch();
                Program.currentPlayer.storage[x, y] = true;
                winControl();
                if (Program.AIOn == true && Program.unbeatableAIOn != true && AI.isPlaying == false) AI.MakeMove();
                if (Program.unbeatableAIOn == true && AI.isPlaying == false) AI.MakeUnbeatableMove();
            }
            else
            {
                Program.PlaySound("D:/eigenes/Programmieren/Sounds/mixkit-cool-interface-click-tone-2568.wav");
                if (AI.isPlaying == false) AI.MakeMove();
                if (AI.isPlaying == false) AI.MakeUnbeatableMove();
            }
            AI.isPlaying = false;
        }

        private void colorChoice(Button button)
        {
            if (Program.currentPlayer.color == System.Drawing.Color.Red) button.BackColor = Color.Red;
            if (Program.currentPlayer.color == System.Drawing.Color.Blue) button.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }

        public void SimulateButtonClick(int buttonNumber)
        {
            switch (buttonNumber)
            {
                case 1: button1.PerformClick(); break;
                case 2: button2.PerformClick(); break;
                case 3: button3.PerformClick(); break;
                case 4: button4.PerformClick(); break;
                case 5: button5.PerformClick(); break;
                case 6: button6.PerformClick(); break;
                case 7: button7.PerformClick(); break;
                case 8: button8.PerformClick(); break;
                case 9: button9.PerformClick(); break;
            }
        }

    }

    class AI
    {
        public static bool isPlaying = false;
        public void MakeMove()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            isPlaying = true;
            PlayArea.SimulateButtonClick(rnd.Next(1, 9));
        }

        public static void MakeUnbeatableMove()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code please? It is almost impossible to suggest any solution without knowing what you are doing and how you are doing to solve the problem.

Comment: @Chetan I have updated my post with the most important parts of my code. I hope it does not make you even more confused...

Comment: You have two basic options here: (1) Pass a Reference to your Form into Class `AI` via the Constructor so you can directly manipulate it, or (2) Make Class `AI` raise a custom EVENT that the Form subscribes to so that it can click its own button when the event is received.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce some of your code:

```
private void colorChoice(Button button)
{
    button.BackColor = (Program.currentPlayer.color == System.Drawing.Color.Red) ? System.Drawing.Color.Red : System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
}

public void SimulateButtonClick(int buttonNumber)
{
    Button btn = this.Controls.Find("button" + buttonNumber, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
    if (btn != null) 
    {
        btn.PerformClick();
    }
}
```